# Sigma js cannot load external gexf

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

Downloaded the sigma.js zip from https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js
to try out the basic loading of gexf files.
Unfortunately , the html - load-external-gexf.html doesnt load up any graph.

```
    <!-- START SIGMA IMPORTS -->
<script src="../src/sigma.core.js"></script>
<script src="../src/conrad.js"></script>
<script src="../src/utils/sigma.utils.js"></script>
<script src="../src/utils/sigma.polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="../src/sigma.settings.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.dispatcher.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.configurable.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.graph.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.camera.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.quad.js"></script>
<script src="../src/captors/sigma.captors.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="../src/captors/sigma.captors.touch.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.canvas.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.webgl.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.nodes.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.nodes.fast.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.edges.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.edges.fast.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.edges.arrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.labels.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.hovers.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.nodes.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curve.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.arrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curvedArrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/middlewares/sigma.middlewares.rescale.js"></script>
<script src="../src/middlewares/sigma.middlewares.copy.js"></script>
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.animation.js"></script>
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.bindEvents.js"></script>
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.drawHovers.js"></script>
<!-- END SIGMA IMPORTS -->
<script src="../plugins/sigma.parsers.gexf/gexf-parser.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/sigma.parsers.gexf/sigma.parsers.gexf.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <style>
    #graph-container {
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="graph-container"></div>
</div>
<script>
/**
 * Here is just a basic example on how to properly display a graph
 * exported from Gephi in the GEXF format.
 *
 * The plugin sigma.parsers.gexf can load and parse the GEXF graph file,
 * and instantiate sigma when the graph is received.
 *
 * The object given as the second parameter is the base of the instance
 * configuration object. The plugin will just add the "graph" key to it
 * before the instanciation.
 */
sigma.parsers.gexf('data/arctic.gexf', {
  container: 'graph-container'
});
</script>
```

The file arctic.gexf is also present under the data directory. 
I am using Google chrome 37

What's the issue? I am able to load other example htmls under the example directory, but the load-external-json.html also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not running this hosted on a server it's happening because of Chrome's default security settings - it won't load files off your hard drive (unless you're running a server).

Using the developer tools you'll see a **XMLHttpRequest cannot load error**.

Using Firefox you won't run into this limitation and you'll be able to load those examples without the need of running a server.